# How to call counsel-projectile-switch-project with a specified project?

Tags: projectile

The logic is that, if the default directory of a buffer has a certain prefix, then call `consule-projectile-switch-project` with a specific project, otherwise simply invoke `counsel-projectile`.

My tetative but failed code is this. The basic idea is to simulate an user input for the desired target project path and followed with an enter key.

```lisp
(defun my-counsel-projectile-ad (fun &rest args)
  (if (string-prefix-p (expand-file-name "~/Documents/notes") 
      (expand-file-name default-directory))
      (progn
        (setq unread-command-events (listify-key-sequence "OneDrive/documents\C-m"))
        (funcall-interactively #'counsel-projectile-switch-project))
    (apply fun args)))

(advice-add #'counsel-projectile :around #'my-counsel-projectile-ad)
```

However, when running with an buffer like `~/Documents/notes/note`, emacs fails with
`wrong argument, wholenump nil`

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do here. is the idea you use counsel-projectile to find a file in the current project, but if the path to that file (in the current project) starts with "~/Documents/notes" you switch out of the project to another one?

Comment: but if the path to current visited file starts with "~/Documents/notes" you switch out of the project to another one?